# LINQ to Object basic Remove

Tags: c#, linq

I've currently got the following code:

```
XElement TEST = XElement.Parse(
    @"<SettingsBundle>
        <SettingsGroup Id=""QAVerificationSettings"">
            <Setting Id=""RegExRules"">True</Setting>
            <Setting Id=""RegExRules123"">
                <RegExRule xmlns:i=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" xmlns=""http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Sdl.Verification.QAChecker.RegEx"">
                    <IgnoreCase>false</IgnoreCase>
                </RegExRule>
            </Setting>
        </SettingsGroup>
    </SettingsBundle>");
TEST.Elements("Setting").Remove();  
var NEW = new XDocument( TEST ); 
var OUT = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\_Texting.xml";
NEW.Save(OUT);
```

I'm expecting;

```
<SettingsBundle>
<SettingsGroup Id=""QAVerificationSettings"">
</SettingsGroup>
</SettingsBundle>
```

But nothing is deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
TEST.Elements("Setting")
```

...will only find elements on the root level, but since `Settings` is nested under `SettingsGroup`, it's easier to just find them among *all* nodes in the tree using `Descendants`.

```
TEST.Descendants("Setting").Remove();
```

...which results in...

```
<SettingsBundle>
  <SettingsGroup Id="QAVerificationSettings" />
</SettingsBundle>
```